# Problems creating tables for Oracle on H2 in memory DB

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, h2, oracle12c

I can't seem to figure out the right combination to get this to work. I have generated DDL from Oracle QL developer with the Quick DDL and the get_ddl functions as well as written my own SQL. All work fine in SQL Plus and SQL Developer, but I can't figure out how to get H2 to accept the SQL.

Ive tried different variations, left off the schema name, etc. Nothing seems to work.

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_SCHEMA.SAVED_SEARCHES(
    SEARCHID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY AUTO_INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOT NULL, 
    NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    USERID VARCHAR2(32 BYTE), 
    WORKGROUPID VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    ONECLICK VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL
)
```

Connection properties:

```
<Context reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
    <Resource 
        name="jdbc/cts" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        removeAbandoned="true" 
        removeAbandonedTimeout="30" 
        maxActive="100" 
        maxIdle="30" 
        maxWait="10000" 
        username="test_schema"  
        password="oracle" 
        driverClassName="com.test.h2.H2Driver" 
        url="jdbc:testh2:mem:testdb;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST_SCHEMA\;SET SCHEMA TEST_SCHEMA" 
        validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" 
    />
</Context>
```

Error:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement: expected "(, NOT, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, NOT, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from studying a syntax of CREATE TABLE statement in H2 database:
http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_table

A simplified syntax is:

```
CREATE TABLE name (
  columnDefinition,
  columnDefinition,
  ....
);
```

where `columnDefinition` is:

http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#column_definition

```
columnName dataType [ AUTO_INCREMENT | IDENTITY [ (startInt [,incrementInt ] ) ]]
```

where elements withins `[]` brackets are optional

As you see Oracle's syntax:

```
columnName dataType GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY AUTO_INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1
```

is completely different than H2's syntax:

```
columnName dataType IDENTITY  (1,1)
```

You need to rewrite the `CREATE TABLE` statement by hand to adapt it to H2 database.

---

Also  H2 doesn't alows for `VARCHAR2` and `(50 BYTE)` length
you need to use just `VARCHAR( 50 )` or more than 50, see this link:
http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#varchar_type

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize H2 had it's own SQL syntax, my fault for not reading the doc.

Comment: After modifying the DDL to be H2 compliant, I now get a table not found SQL error. I have the DB_CLOSE_DELAY setting set. Thoughts?